# Passing values to Custom authorization policy ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

Hi I want to pass parameters to the custom policy in asp.net core. As i know so far i can only do

```
[Authorize(Policy="Over21")]
My Action(){
}
```

but i want to do

```
[Authorize(Policy="Over21",Para="AnotherValue")]
My Action(){
    }
```

so i decided to extend Authorize attribute and then do this.

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Permission;    
        public MyAuthorizationAttribute(string policy, string permission)
            : base(policy)
        {
            Permission = permission;
        } 

    }
```

Then do this

```
[MyAuthorization("MyPolicy","CanDoPermission")]
My Action(){
    }
```

The custom authorization handler is still called when i debug and so now i want a way to get the permission property from the `AuthorizationHandlerContext context`. I realize that i can find this property when i drill down during debug

```
context->Resource->Filters
```

Among this list i find all objects of type AuthorizeFilter and further drill down to `AuthorizeData->Resultview` this also is a list that contains my  MyAuthorization object. I use a debut tool to do this but i dont know how to get MyAuthorization instance that applies to the specific action being called?

This is the furthest i get.

```
var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;

            foreach (var filterMetadata in mvcContext.Filters)
            {
                if (filterMetadata.GetType().Name != "AuthorizeFilter") continue;

                var claimAttribute = filterMetadata as AuthorizeFilter;
                if (claimAttribute != null)
                {
                    var data = claimAttribute.AuthorizeData;
                }
```

Am not sure what to do next to get this object. I am hoping there is an easier way to get these values from the context.